# Can a statement begin with "Which"?

Tags: sentence-construction

May one write something like: "We shall need many snarks to this end. However, they can be fed carrots and the latter are cheap this year. *Which* makes me hope..."?

Comment: Sure, _Which_ also functions as _that_, whenever you feel unsure about using _which_, try to figure out that question with _that_. Check this out: http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/which/1.html

Comment: Supplementary (non-restrictive) relative clauses with the form of a main clause are not common but they do occur. They are always of the _wh_ type and can never be introduced with "that". In your example, the relative pronoun "which" is anaphoric by virtue of having the entire previous clause as antecedent. We understand that the fact that they can be fed carrots and the latter are cheap this year makes me hope ...

Comment: One situation where they do occur is when an entire paragraph is the antecedent for "which". In situations like that, the relative clause must take the form of a new sentence since "which" does not refer to only the preceding clause, but several clauses. It's not poor style at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence, when put on the page, would typically be punctuated as follows, with the relative clause *not* starting a new (typographic) sentence :

...the latter are cheap this year, which makes me hope...

or

... the latter are cheap this year—which makes me hope...

The antecedent of **which** in this case is not a particular noun but the nominal idea expressed in the preceding statement(s), and so the *which*-clause is tacked onto the preceding sentence, so to speak, adding new information rather than modifying a previous word or phrase.

An alternative would be:

... the latter are cheap this year, and this makes me hope...

where **this** again refers back to the idea expressed in the preceding clause(s) rather than to a particular word or phrase.

Comment: So, is your answer - No?

Comment: @Serguei - correct; you would normally begin a new *phrase* with "which", but not a new *sentence*, because the which-phrase is just explaining something about something else in the sentence.

Comment: Thus, when I see such a sentence (I do every now and then) I should take it for a sign of poor style or, say, an archaism?

Comment: No, you would just take it as an example of the fact that punctuation is merely a set of agreed-upon conventions which can vary, depending on the type of publication (newspaper, magazine, academic journal, blog, fiction, and so forth) and on other factors too (year/century of publication, country of publication, etc). But *typically*, as I said, you would not see a new sentence in situations like your example.